# send friend request and message to offline user in xmpp ios

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire

I am working in XMPP project with openfire server.
I want to send friend request and messages to user who is offline.

I am able to send the friend request and message to the user who is online by the below code :-

```
- (XMPPRoster *)xmppRoster {
    return [[self appDelegate] xmppRoster];
}

-(IBAction)SendFriendRequest:(id)sender
{
    XMPPJID *newBuddy = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"test1@192.168.4.21"];

    [[[self appDelegate]xmppRoster]addUser:newBuddy withNickname:@"test user 1"];
}
```